# Intellisense for PowerShell splatting in vscode?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, intellisense, parameter-splatting

My understanding is that splatting variables is the preferred/recommended way to make longer function calls in PowerShell scripts. However, I use vscode as my primary IDE and understandably, extracting the parameters into a hashtable and splatting them makes intellisense unusable.

Is there any library/framework/vscode extension for splatting that allows the use of intellisense by way of naming convention or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a relatively old question but whilst looking for similar I came across Editor Services Command Suite which looks like it may be useful. It allows you to write the command out and then convert it to a splatted version:
[ESCS github repo](https://github.com/SeeminglyScience/EditorServicesCommandSuite)

It was this blog post by Rob Sewell (sqldbawithabeard) which brought it to my attention: [blog post](https://sqldbawithabeard.com/2018/03/11/easily-splatting-powershell-with-vs-code/)

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out!

Answer (score 0):

> understandably, extracting the parameters into a hashtable and splatting them makes intellisense unusable.

I assumed the same thing recently—and it's likely changed since you first asked the question—but vscode apparently supports intellisense for splatted arguments now. I came looking for information on it (and finding this question) because I was so stunned by seeing suggestions for splatted arguments!

### Before

`$args` here is going to be splatted to `New-AzCdnOrigin`, but hasn't been yet:

[image]

So no suggestions so far:

[image]

### After

[image]

Suggestions from the parameters of `New-AzCdnOrigin`, even omitting those already added:

[image]